# How to rewriting .php files to .asp

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using below code for changing the URL but its not working. My folder structure is:   `www.abc.com/maindri/index.php`

**htaccess:**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^home.asp?$ index.php
 RewriteRule ^invesys.php?$ invesys-capital.php
 RewriteRule ^stocks?$ stocks.php
 RewriteRule ^performance?$ performance.php
```

Trying to change URL for first time.
I would like to show URL in browser home.asp intead that index.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must not only include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem, but also the desired behavior and a specific problem or error. _Not working_ is not a proper problem description. What do you expect and what do you actually get? Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27763596/edit) your post.

Comment: Your configuration seems correct, but you must make sure that the AllowOverride directive is on in the vhost config.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and where are all `.php` files located?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home\.asp$ index.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```